# Setting the width of a view bigger than its parent's?

Tags: android

Here is my xmls (there are basically two views: a linear [`B`] inside a relative [`A`])

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/A"
android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
android:layout_height= "wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/B"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>

</<RelativeLayout>
```

I'm setting the width of `B` as 10 times of the screen width, namely `w*10`:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams para = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w*10, h);
B.setLayoutParams(para);
```

When I animate `B`,

```
ObjectAnimator animation2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(B, "x", -w)
```

it shows that the width of `B` is `w` rather than `w*10`, as if `A`, who is being the parent view, is limiting its width.

What should I do to have `B`'s width as `w*10`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075220/how-can-i-make-a-child-larger-than-the-parent-in-android

Answer (score 1):

A child view must layout completely within its parent.  You cannot ever be bigger than your parent, in either direction.  So yes, a parent will limit the width of a child.  Of course, since your parent is set to wrap content it should grow to surround B.  Have you tried calling requestLayout to make it resize itself?