# How can I make a child larger than the parent in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to insert an imageView into a Relative/Linear layout in such a way that the imageView is larger than the parent. So far I have tried a negative margin and padding on the imageView and set clipChildren to false on the parent, but nothing seems to help. Has anyone done something like this before?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/text_black"
            android:paddingBottom="-100dp"
            android:paddingLeft="-100dp"
            android:paddingRight="-100dp"
            android:paddingTop="-100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Basically I am trying to achieve something like this...
state1 - Has a series of viewgroups. When I click on one of them, I get state 2 where the image inside the viewgroup is visible fully and overlaps any of the surrounding viewgroups without affecting their position.

[image: State 1]
[image: State 2]

Comment: What do you expect the behavior of this ImageView to be? Should it scroll, or should the excess content simply be cropped off?

Comment: The imageView should be visible completely over the parent, unclipped.

Comment: can you upload an image or hand made sketch of what you want to show? and what exactly you wish to achieve ? Will better be able to help then.

Comment: Added some more details.

Comment: Use another FrameLayout the same level as your current FrameLayout and put the bigger ImageView centered or padded properly.

Answer (score 0):

so why don't u just give  parent to Width and Height= wrapcontent

Answer (score 0):

The size of the container is limited by teh Parent, so it is not possible to put a container inside that is larger (you couldn't put a 5 liter box inside a 3 liter box).

ImageView has an "scale" attribute that will clip or adjust your view (and keep it sized appropriately).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html